# How to break for loop when it found 1 match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

There is one excel file Email Info.xlsx, and there are many reports by Vendor name, both have the same column name "Vendor". This function will display all emails with identical vendors from both dataframes/excels. How to make it break in the first match? Thank you!

```
def DisplayExample():
    # Load email info into dataframe
    try:
        now_date = datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')  # current date
        email_info = pd.read_excel(email_file_path)
        email_info.fillna('', inplace=True)
        
        outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        for index, row in email_info.iterrows():
            mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
            mail.To = row["Email"]
            mail.CC = row["CC"]
            mail.Subject = f"{row['Vendor']} - Report {now_date}"
            mail.Body = ''
            try:
                excel_file = f"{row['Vendor']}.xlsx"
                attached_excel_path = os.path.join(path, excel_file)
                mail.Attachments.Add(Source=attached_excel_path)
            except Exception as e:
                messagebox.showerror('Python Error', f"This vendor {row['Vendor']} doesn't match in Email Info and Report")
            
            mail.Display()
            # mail.Send()
            if something here...:
                break
        
    except Exception as e:
         messagebox.showerror('Python Error', e)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "both dataframes/excels"? There's only one dataframe.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry, yes there is only one dataframe, Thank you for the quick response. I put the Vendor name into a list, and check if row['Vendor'] in list: break. It works perfectly now. Thank you again!!!

Comment: If you want to prevent adding attachments for the same vendor multiple times, use a `set` to hold all the vendor names that you've seen. Then check if the vendor name is already in the set before adding the attachment.

Comment: @Barmar that's the perfect answer. Thank you sir!